# Will transactions stop other code from reading inconsistent data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a stored procedure that inserts into several tables in a single transaction. I know transactions can maintain data consistency in non-concurrent situations by allowing rollbacks after errors, power failure, etc., but if other code selects from these tables before I commit the transaction, could it possibly select inconsistent data?

Basically, can you select uncommitted transactions?

If so, then how do people typically deal with this?

Comment: isn't stuff that happens in a stored proc put in a hidden transaction anyhow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on the ISOLATION LEVEL of the read query rather than the transaction. This can be set centrally on the connection or provided in the SELECT hint.

See:
Connection side: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx

Database side: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: +1. Basically yes, there is a way to read uncommited data IF YOU WANT. Has to be set explicitly.

Comment: Great, one more question: From within the transaction can I select from another table which I inserted previously into earlier in the transaction?

Comment: @nw: Yes - unless your DBMS is broken.  Your transaction should be able to see the changes it made.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by Aliostad, this depends on the selected [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#READ_UNCOMMITTED).  The Wikipedia article has examples of the different common scenarios.

So yes, you can choose to get uncommitted data, but only by choice.  I never did that and I have to admit that the idea seems a bit ... dangerous to me.  But there are probably reasonable use cases.

Comment: Sure, often reporting queries that aggregate millions of rows don't need to be transactionally consistent, imagine a table that is collecting web traffic hits for a high-volume web site. How long should I wait to get a 100% accurate count (never mind that I'm slowing down other readers and writers), when a ballpark is good enough (e.g. are we at 5 million hits yet, or is the hit count exactly 5,123,421)?

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the good example of a reasonable example of dirty reads!

Comment: Sure, another thing is when trying to just get a count for a table, for some of the same reasons, it may not be necessary to touch the table at all. It can be much more efficient to pull the counts from sys.dm_db_partition_stats for the whole table or if it is a subset of data that is supported by a filtered index, as long as you understand that those counts will be off if there are any active transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Aliostad's answer:

By default, other reading processes won't read data that is being changed (uncommitted, aka "dirty reads"). This applies to all clients and drivers

You have to override this default deliberately with the NOLOCK hint or changing isolation level to allow "dirty reads".